# Segue removes tabBarItem.badgeValue

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I have a custom `TabBarController`and on one of the `Tab Bar Items` I have a round red counter. The first `Tab Tab Item` presents a summary View Controller. The second `Tab Bar Item` presents a menu embedded in a `Navigation Controller` The `Tab Bar Counter`works fine across the board, except when I segue back from the summary View Controller. Then the counter disappears. I have tried to load the counter in the `customTabBarController`:

```
import UIKit

class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if tabBarCounter != 0
        {
            let vc = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.last
            vc?.tabBarItem.badgeValue = "\(tabBarCounter)"
            vc?.tabBarItem.badgeColor = UIColor.red
        }
    }
}
```

Screendump of storyboard. (The bottom `ViewController` is the one I´m having trouble with. Segue highlited)
[image]

Comment: You are subclassing `UITabBarController`, you can set the tabBarItem property directly and don't forget to call super in your viewDidAppear method `override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
            tabBarItem.badgeValue = "value"
            tabBarItem.badgeColor = .red
    }`

Comment: Perfect! That did the trick